# how to install windows 10 on hundreds of computer efficiently

Tags: windows, windows-10

In about 5 days time i will be assembling and installing software on about 150 independent and identical computers. I am thinking of a way to efficiently install the software on each computers. The same programs will be installed on each computer.

Now doing it individually will take a very long time and is very labor intensive. The way i was thinking of doing this is

To first install windows on 1 computer, it has to be inactivated we will be activating it later. install all the necessary programs, all free programs will be installed, and those that requires licenses will not be installed but the installer will be left on the computer. A remote program will also be installed (e.g. teamviewer). With that done, that hard drive will then be cloned for all remaining computers. when all the computers are assembled and ready, they will then be connected to a single network so i can remote in to the computer activate windows and program licenses.

The only thing that i do not like about this method is that each computer have a specified name that it must use. These computers do not belong to a single organization but will be spread out to multiple. While remoting to each computer, i must then change the computer name (the one displayed on the lock screen) and the folder path C:/User/myname to correspond to its new name.

is there a more effecient way of doing this?

Comment: Purchase hardware that clones multiple HDDs at once from a single source.  How you manage and deploy software after that can vary greatly based on your individual requirements.  Changing the name of a machine through a script, before you add it to the domain (automatically), is not a difficult task.

Comment: There’s more efficient, and proper, ways to do this. What you’re trying to do will not work. A system should be setup in audit mode and properly sysprep’d before cloning the drive. Microsoft Deployment Toolkit is the mechanism typically used to completely automate this process. But their are others. We typically don’t install software before the base image is sealed. The software is usually installed by script, after the OOBE stage of the deployment. Look at windows zerotouch deployment or windows autopilot. In any case the process can be 100% automated after a couple of button clicks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say look for windows lite touch deployment.

Comment: @Ramhound i do not think i can get that hardware in 5 days, shipping alone takes atleast  7 days in my area (that already the fastest).

Comment: @Appleoddity skimming through what i see, does this require a organizational liscence? the client opted to buy individual licenses for each computers as this would solve a lot of nuisances for them.

Comment: @Jack no. Licensing is a different and independent challenge. MDT doesn’t care. However when you purchase individual licenses it is usually embedded in the hardware of the PC. So, you have to use a “generic” key to complete deployment and follow it up with a script which activates windows with the hardware key. See my answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1100314/how-microsoft-licences-work-with-mdt-and-wds-deployment/1100340#1100340 you may need a different generic key depending on which version of windows you are deploying.